# Shell script to iterate files. Got error on line 3

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /home/username/git/*/
do
    for file in "$dir"/*
    do
        if [[ -f $file ]]
        then
            echo   "$file"
        fi
    done
done
```

When I try to run it. I got

```
syntax error near unexpected toke' `do
'rocTest.sh: line 3: `do
```

Why?

Comment: works for me... (bash version 4.1.2)

Comment: Is that the exact error message you're seeing or did it get scrumpled when you posted? If it is, you probably have some funky chars in your script.

Comment: Check whether you have some funny character right after `do` on the third line.  Put the cursor after `f` in the second `for` and keep hitting backspace until you delete `o` in `do`.  Then type `o` followed by CR, then `f`.  Omit the indentation for now - you can fix it later.

Comment: Or paste `hexdump -C ?rocTest.sh` for us to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"$file"` (with quotes) consistently to deal with "problematic" file names; in particular `if [[ -f $file ]]` should be

`if [[ -f "$file" ]] ...`

Note that bash is not always in /bin (e.g. FreeBSD places it in /usr/local/bin); for wider portability, either use

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

or `#!/bin/sh` and make sure to **remove bash-isms** (e.g. use `checkbashisms` on Debian/Ubuntu). E.g. write `if test -f "$file"` instead of `[[ -f "$file" ]]`